# Webrequest doesn't include authentication header

Tags: c#, webrequest

I am running the following in c# to send a login request to an API.  However, according to Fiddler, it is not sending an Authentication Header.  I am a rookie, so it is likely something simple.

```
NetworkCredential netcreds=new NetworkCredential(username,password);
CredentialCache credentials = new CredentialCache();
credentials.Add(new Uri(LoginUrl.ToString()),"Basic",netcreds);
Uri LoginUri = new Uri(LoginUrl);
WebRequest AuthRequest = WebRequest.Create(LoginUri);
AuthRequest.Credentials = credentials;        `  

AuthRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding,@"application/*+xml;version=1.5");`
```